# Centering rectangle with size vs width/height properties

Tags: paperjs

Why will the rectangle be ***centered***, when setting the .size property?

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.center = view.center;
rect.size = new Size(100, 200);
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rect);
path.fillColor = 'red';
```

Why will the rectangle ***not be centered***, when setting the .width and .height properties?

```
var rect = new Rectangle();
rect.center = view.center;
rect.width = 100;
rect.height = 200;
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rect);
path.fillColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious too and took a look to source code.

That happens because updating width / height directly only changes the point where bottomRight point should be. You only tells to "grow" in X and Y direction.

On the other hand, using ".size", which is a setter
[(method here)](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/basic/Rectangle.js#L287)
does more than that. It re-calculates X & Y based on an internal state called "_sx" & "_sy" (which will have 0.5 - center - as value by default. [More here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/basic/Rectangle.js#L290)).

The key is here:

```
...
if (sx) {
    this.x += (this.width - w) * sx;
}
if (sy) {
    this.y += (this.height - h) * sy;
}
...
```

When "sx" and/or "sy" are 0.5 the rectangle centers (by default).